# yii2 прием get в методе

Tags: yii2

Никак не допрет, почему не принимает параметр

```
public function actionView($slug)
```

в вью так

```
 <?=\yii\helpers\Html::a('LINK',[\yii\helpers\Url::to(['portfolio/view', 'slug' => $portfolio->slug])]); ?>
```

дебажу в методе слаг который должен прилететь  ,  NULL

понятно, что я могу принять через реквест гет и это решает проблему. Но хочу разобаться почему так не прилетает

config

```
 'showScriptName' => false, 
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true, //отключаем index.php
        'rules' => [
           'about' =>  'site/about',
            'portfolio/<slug:\w+>' => 'portfolio/view',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка в ядре была, после обновления, проблема исчезла

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка на уровне роутинга. Убедитесь, что указанный параметр указан в роутере. Если используются ЧПУ, то примерно так: `'controller_name/<slug:\w+> => 'controller_name/view'`. В левой части - URL с указанием ожидаемого параметра, в правой - контроллер и action.

Comment: это ествественно указано

Comment: И url генерируется `/portfolio/slug`?

Comment: да вместо слаг из бд тянется значение